# Jquery PhoneMask - Unexpected Behavior

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using jquery phonemasking which started to behave weird. Able to get mask on textbox on focus and when i start entering numbers it fills in alternate positions separated by _ which ends up with only 5 numbers. something like this 
"(*9*) 8_6-_5_6". Here is my code.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone1" runat="server" CssClass="phoneMask" ToolTip="Phone 1" MaxLength="20" ValidationGroup="ChildValidationGroup"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="hidden" id="noPhoneMask" class="noPhoneMask" runat="server" value="0" />




    function fncPhoneMasking() {
        if ($('.noPhoneMask').val() == "0") { $('.phoneMask').mask("(999) 999-999");                                           
}
    }


$(function () {
    fncPhoneMasking();
});
```

Can someone help me out what is wrong? Everything seems correct but cannot find a solution for this behavior.

Comment: it is like (_9_) 8_6-_5_6. Filling up alternate positions as we type.

Comment: Is this correct? ...{ $('.phoneMask')... maybe should be .noPhoneMask

Comment: trying to add mask on control with css class phoneMask based on the hidden field value with css class nophoneMask. Able to get mask though but with weird behavior.